# To Chop or not to Chop

Tags: functions, numerics, maximize

If I run the command

```
  ResourceFunction[ "GlobalMaxima"][{x*y + 2*y*z + 6*x, x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 36}, {x, y, z}]
```

This returns a closed form solution of

[image]

If I take $N[]$, it returns

[image]

Adding a [*Chop*](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Chop.html) produces a max

```
  57.6271 at x = 3.7642, y = 3.68959, z = 2.86666
```

If I run the command

```
  N[Maximize[{x*y + 2*y*z + 6*x, x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 36}, {x, y, z}]]
```

I get the chopped version of the result.

My question is, how do users know that they should chop a result in general (sure, the imaginaries are quite small) but why does one command show them and the other does not?

Is a user expected to test the results to determine if chopping should be used or is this never true?

**Aside:** It appears that MathJax/LaTex is not working at the moment for some reason hence the pictures above.

Comment: **how do users know that they should chop a result in general** well, you can always automatically add `Chop` to the result. This way no need to guess. If it is needed, it will be used, if not, it will not affect the result, right?

Comment: So why does the numerical result return it at all in those cases? Yes, as a user I can do all sorts of things and massage outputs, but that seems clumsy somehow.

Comment: `"GlobalMaxima"` returned the results in the form of radical expressions that can produce imaginary artifacts particularly when using machine precision. However, if you `FullSimplify` the results they will be in the form of `Root` expressions (same as those produced by `Maximize`) that will avoid the imaginary artifacts when `N` is used. In general, use arbitrary-precision (e.g., `N[#, 15]&`) rather than machine precision (i.e., `N`) to get better precision.

Comment: It's better to use `N[res, prec]` with `prec >= $MachinePrecision`, imo, if you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Look at the output of [`Maximize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Maximize):

```
Maximize[{x*y + 2*y*z + 6*x, x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 36}, {x, y, z}] //InputForm
```

> {6*Root[{-108 - 72*#1 + 9*#1^2 + 5*#1^3 & , -144 - 6*#1 + 7*#1^2 + 5*#2^2 & },
> {3, 2}] + Root[{-108 - 72*#1 + 9*#1^2 + 5*#1^3 & ,
> -144 - 6*#1 + 7*#1^2 + 5*#2^2 & }, {3, 2}]*Root[-108 - 72*#1 + 9*#1^2 + 5*#1^3 & ,
> 3, 0] + 2*Root[{-108 - 72*#1 + 9*#1^2 + 5*#1^3 & ,
> -144 - 6*#1 + 7*#1^2 + 5*#2^2 & , -18*#2 - 21*#1*#2 + 5*#1^2*#2 + 36*#3 & },
> {3, 2, 1}]*Root[-108 - 72*#1 + 9*#1^2 + 5*#1^3 & , 3, 0],
> {x -> Root[{-108 - 72*#1 + 9*#1^2 + 5*#1^3 & , -144 - 6*#1 + 7*#1^2 + 5*#2^2 & },
> {3, 2}], y -> Root[-108 - 72*#1 + 9*#1^2 + 5*#1^3 & , 3, 0],
> z -> Root[{-108 - 72*#1 + 9*#1^2 + 5*#1^3 & , -144 - 6*#1 + 7*#1^2 + 5*#2^2 & ,
> -18*#2 - 21*#1*#2 + 5*#1^2*#2 + 36*#3 & }, {3, 2, 1}]}}

The output of the resource function uses nested radicals. When numericizing nested radicals, the radicals may be complex, with the imaginary parts cancelling after arithmetic. It is basically unavoidable when working with radicals. The output of [`Maximize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Maximize) consists of [`Root`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root) objects. When numericizing [`Root`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root) objects, Mathematica is able to determine whether the output is real, and avoids generating any imaginary parts if not needed. This is why chopping is necessary when you have arithmetic with radicals, while chopping is generally not needed when the output consists of [`Root`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root) objects. Just another reason to prefer [`Root`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root) objects over radicals.

Comment: (+1) @Carl Woll Nice explanation!